# Adding Html to a calculated columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column

My scenario : I have a calculated column which need to show a specific image based on another choice column(Status:closed,open or active).

I have set the calculated column type as Number.
I tried to use the following code,but it end up showing as plain text.The code below is the simplest html tag i am testing with,which is not working either.

```
="<DIV><a href='https://tenatname.sharepoint.com/sites/projectx/t/Lists/Project%20Status%20Reports/All%20Items.aspx'>Branding</a></DIV>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has disabled the use (or misuse) of the calculated column in SharePoint Online and SharePoint On-premise based on your current patch-level.

> Some users have added HTML markup or script elements to calculated
>   fields. This is an undocumented use of the feature, and we will block
>   the execution of custom markup in calculated fields in SharePoint
>   Online from June 13, 2017 onwards. The June 2017 Public Update (PU)
>   and later PUs will make blocking a configurable option for on-premises
>   use in SharePoint Server 2016 and SharePoint Server 2013.
>
> We are changing calculated fields to block the execution of custom
>   markup. This mean that calculated fields that contain any unsupported
>   markup will not display correctly.
>
> This change went into effect on June 13, 2017. Administrators can
>   request an extension through September 10, 2017 at the latest. During
>   this extension, execution of custom markup in calculated fields will
>   not be blocked. This request can be submitted through Microsoft
>   Support. However, beginning September 10, 2017, all unsupported markup
>   will be ignored.

[Handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032106/handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-fields)

Use CSR instead. I also recommend using the google chrome plugin called [Cisar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo) to get you started.

I'm thinking that something like this might work for you:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

  function getBaseHtml(ctx) {
    return SPClientTemplates["_defaultTemplates"].Fields.default.all.all[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.FieldType][ctx.BaseViewID](ctx);
  }

  function init() {

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

      // OnPreRender: function(ctx) { },

     Templates: {
          Fields: {
              "Status": {
                  View: function(ctx) {
                      var status = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
                        switch (status) { 
                          case "Closed": 
                              return "<img src="icon.png" height="32" width="32">"; 
                              break; 
                          case "Open": 
                              return "<img src="icon.png" height="32" width="32">"; 
                              break;
                        case "Active": 
                              return "<img src="icon.png" height="32" width="32">"; 
                              break; 
                       }
                  }
              }
          }
      },

      // OnPostRender: function(ctx) { },

      ListTemplateType: 100

    });
  }

  RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/SiteAssets/renderStatus.js"), init);
  init();

});
```

[Customize a list view in SharePoint Add-ins using client-side rendering](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/customize-a-list-view-in-sharepoint-add-ins-using-client-side-rendering)

[Client-side rendering (JS Link) code samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a)

Comment: Any other alternative for my scenario.

Comment: @KeshavTaurah, Updated.

Comment: As mentioned by Chris CSR is the best option

Answer (score 1):

The following link give an alternative for 2013 and 2016 on prem.  A web app setting has been added to allow HTML Rendering in Calculated Columns via PowerShell:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40146.sharepoint-online20162013-html-rendering-in-calculated-columns.aspx