# Change background color on sharepoint list based on another column without CSR

Tags: 2013, workflow

I'm currently trying to change the background color based on the date and time a task is due. Unfortunately, our head office has disabled the ability to use Scripts and edit CSS on our sharepoint site (The page gets marked for non-compliance and gets taken down until we edit it again). We can edit web parts in the web interface and create workflows.

Is there a way to change the background color through workflows?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can change the background color or any CSS using the workflows.

This can only be done by using CSR or any custom CSS code.

However you can create a new calculated column and show the color coding for that column only and not for complete row. Check example below:

[Using calculated columns to add color coding to your SharePoint lists](https://www.google.com/amp/s/blog.splibrarian.com/2012/06/06/using-calculated-columns-to-add-color-coding-to-your-sharepoint-lists/amp/)

**Note**:

1. Microsoft has disabled the use (or misuse) of the calculated column in SharePoint Online and SharePoint On-premise based on your current patch-level.
2. So, you need to try creating a calculated field and adding HTML through formula. If it works then fine else you have to use CSR or custom CSS.

[Adding Html to a calculated columns](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/241364/adding-html-to-a-calculated-columns/264147)